# Insert symbol in the Value xaml

Tags: xaml, uwp

```
<controls:RadialProgressBar Margin="10,0,0,0" x:Name="RadialProgressBarControl" 
           Value="0"                                     
           Minimum="0"
           Maximum="180"
           Thickness="0"
           Outline="#FFD6DCDA"
           Foreground="#FF9646E6"
           Width="300"
           Height="300" FontFamily="Palatino Linotype">
                    </controls:RadialProgressBar>
                    <TextBlock Canvas.ZIndex="100" Margin="10,0,0,0" FontFamily="Palatino Linotype" FontSize="55" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FF786DDB" Text="{x:Bind RadialProgressBarControl.Value, Mode=OneWay}">

            while (RadialProgressBarControl.Value < 180)
            {
                RadialProgressBarControl.Value += 1;
                RadialProgressBarControl.Thickness += 0.15;
                await Task.Delay(5);
            }
```

I have 2 problem

1. *is how can I insert the "%" to the  ?*
2. *I want my circle "path" change the color while load the value from one to 180*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is how can I insert the "%" to the ?

If you want to insert `%`to your `TextBlock`, you could create a `TextConverter` inherit [`IValueConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.ivalueconverter). And use it to format text like the follow.

```
internal class TextConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return string.Format("{0} %", value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:TextConverter x:Key="MyConverter" />
</Page.Resources>

<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind RadialProgressBarControl.Value, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"></TextBlock>
```

> I want my circle "path" change the color while load the value from one to 180

You could set the foreground of `RadialProgressBarControl` in the code behind with [`SolidColorBrush`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.solidcolorbrush) dynamically.

```
Color Tem = new Color();
while (RadialProgressBarControl.Value < 180)
{
    RadialProgressBarControl.Value += 1;
    RadialProgressBarControl.Thickness += 0.15;
    Tem.A = 255;
    Tem.R += 1;
    Tem.B += 1;
    Tem.G += 1;
    RadialProgressBarControl.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Tem);
    await Task.Delay(5);
}
```

Comment: Thanks the TextBlock a little complicated but I will figure it out. Is this C# fundamental ? What I c# at my school touch nothing about this

Comment: There is a problem Tem.A is define as byte

Comment: I want to increase 1.1375 for example, it would be a double format. how to fix this ?

Comment: Please try to use [`Math.Round()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75ks3aby(v=vs.110).aspx).